# SQL JOIN when empty link still show row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables:

**patient:**

```
| patientid | name  | address |
|    45     | jelle | adres 2 |
|    23     | piet  | adres 6 |
|    11     | kees  | adres 4 |
```

**agenda:**

```
| agendaid | patientid | datum      | time    | 
|    1     |     45    | 2020-05-12 |  12:05  |
|    2     |     45    | 2020-07-11 |  16:02  |
|    3     |     11    | 2020-02-10 |  10:35  |
```

I want to get all patients with their upcoming appointment from `agenda`
I tried to run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM patient LEFT JOIN agenda ON patient.patientid = agenda.patientid WHERE agenda.datum >= CURDATE()
```

But this one returns only patients that have an appointment in the future.
I want to receive all patients, even if they don't have an appointment in the future.

The desired result should be this:

```
| patientid | name  | address | agendaid | patientid |   datum    | time  |
|    45     | jelle | adres 2 |    2     |    45     | 2020-07-11 | 16:02 | 
|    23     | piet  | adres 6 |          |           |            |       |
|    11     | kees  | adres 4 |    3     |    11     | 2020-02-10 | 10:35 |
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?
I created an `SQL fiddle` for you guys to check out!
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6eecc4/1

As you can see It returns multiple rows for each patient when he has multiple appointments and does not return patients that have no appointments in the future.

Comment: Tag correctly. You are not using sql server as it does not have a curdate() function. Your fiddle is using MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the filtering condition to the `ON` clause.  Otherwise, you turn the outer join into an inner join:

```
SELECT p.*, a.*
FROM patient p LEFT JOIN
     agenda a
     ON p.patientid = a.patientid AND a.datum >= CURDATE();
```

Comment: Now the patient without an appointment appears, Thanks! But I want only one row for each patient. is that possible too?

Comment: @Jbadminton Not without a subquery as your join criteria specifying that you want the min datum per patient

Comment: @Jbadminton . . . I would suggest that you ask a new question to focus on the "returning one row for each patient".   Although that might be buried in this question, the question seems to be much more about returning the non-matching rows.